# GoCD with Visual Studio Team Service (VSTS)

Tags: go-cd

Have anyone successfully used GoCD with Visual Studio Team Service?

I tried the following when trying to add Material:

1. **Type:** "Team Foundation Server"
2. **URL:** https://ourvso.visualstudio.com
3. **Domain:** I left this one empty
4. **Username:** firas.r (extracted from firas.r@ourdomain.com)
5. **Password:** my VSTS password
6. **Project Path:** the correct project path (am sure about it)

But I keep getting the error message: *"Access denied connecting to TFS server https://ourvso.visualstudio.com/ (authenticating as firas.r@ourdomain.com)"*

When I tried the specific values:

**Domain:** ourdomain

**Username:** firas.r@ourdomain.com

I get the error message: *"This server requires federated authentication but no mechanism was available to handle it."*

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You must create an "Alternative authentication credential" in VSTS

1. In VSTS go to the profile menu
2. Click on Security
3. Click on the Alternate authentication credentials
4. Add the username (secondary) and password

Then use this new username in your GoCD configuration. This Works for me.